# Como mudar um valor de um Custom Data

Tags: javascript, html, css, atributos

To criando uma pagina onde vai um botão do youtube para se inscrever, queria de alguma forma mudar uma custom data que esta nele.

`<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="full" data-count="hidden" id="youtube"> </div>`

seria o data-layout queria que o valor dele fosse para default quando chegasse a um certo tamanho de tela, mais nao to sabendo como mudar esse valor dentro del em javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAtribbute`:

```
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('g-ytsubscribe')[0].
div.setAtribbute('data-layout', 'default').
```